# What are the possible solutions to host an internal website for a company using google cloud platform?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, hosting, vpn, google-cloud-dns

I developed an internal portal that is relevant to the engineering team. I restricted access to the portal by implementing **Sign in With Google** and as expected it is only accessible to our organization email-ids only. Now, I want to host the portal and we use Google Cloud Platform. I want to further restrict access to the portal within the organization.

What are the possible solutions to host the portal internally using Google Cloud Platform? If I host the portal and gave access to public, what could be the possible security implications?

Comment: Can you add details about the architecture of the portal? A wild guess would be, if it's micro-service based portal, deploy it on GKE . Another option for frontend, deploy on App Engine

Comment: @nischaygoyal It is just a ReactJS application which makes XHR requests to read the JSON files stored in GCS bucket and display the data on the webpage

Comment: If it’s a reactJS Application, in the end it’s static assets and I would suggest host it on the GCS and give access only to spcific group of Users which is in your company

Comment: If I host the portal as you suggested, Can anyone who has the URL open the page?

Comment: You can give access to specific set of  groups and they should be able to access the application

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that how a browser/client knows that the user is authorized to access the portal? My goal is to not even open the portal URL to outside people.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your storage bucket also has to confidential.

Comment: Yeah. Suppose, if my portal is hosted at reports.example.com, then someone(outside of the organization) who has this link should get 404 or 403

Comment: Something like it should be accessible within the VPN. I want to know the other possible solutions apart from VPN.

Comment: In this case, host your website on App-Engine which will expose a Public-Facing Url and then implement a Firewall rule - `denyAll` which ensures nobody would be able to access the website and then implement another firewall rule which allows a specific range of IPs (Your company's IP range)

Comment: Ours is a remote-first culture company and our engineering team spread across the U.S and European countries. Sometimes many of us, go to co-working spaces and work there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214567/discussion-between-anesh-and-nischay-goyal).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your concept, you are running a Web portal to authenticate your organization users to access your Frontend application, which retrieves information on a GCS bucket to be displayed on this Web page.
In this situation, the [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap) ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/how-to)) that could fit your needs.
The IAP lets you manage access to applications running in the App Engine standard environment, App Engine flexible environment, Compute Engine, and GKE. IAP establishes a central authorization layer for applications accessed by HTTPS, so you can adopt an application-level access control model instead of using network-level firewalls or VPNs. When you turn on IAP, you must also use [signed headers](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto) or the App Engine standard environment [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#users) to secure your app.
In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/security/showcase#network-security) you can see a quick example of how you can control access to your web apps and VMs in GCP using the IAP feature.